# What's the tip for protecting your laptop from damaging during mining?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, cpu-mining

I know using low-end hardware like laptop isn't a good idea, but I still want to know what mining condition could damage my laptop and how can I prevent it.

### Things I've heard

- Break every hour

In my memory, I've heard someone said let your laptop take a break every hour of mining.

- Let your CPU cool

Flip your laptop to cool down your CPU better if your laptop's vent are pointing downward.

- Plug in the power

Someone said, plugging power in modern laptops make it run faster.

---

What's right and what's wrong? I'm not pretty sure if every method is good for my laptop, who can point mt out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the mentioned points is really correct.

1) Break every hour

I don't see how that could help in any way, really.

2) Let your CPU cool

Your CPU should not get to hot but letting the CPU cool down and then start again isn't the answer. The real answer is, don't let it run all the time on 100%. If you are mining you have to set the number of threads. The more threads the more your CPU is occupied. If you worry that your CPU might get to hot then don't use the maximum threads possible.

3) Plug in the power

That one is actually kind of correct. If you mine with your laptop then it can be that your laptop is set up so that it will not use the full processing power if not plugged in. If that's the case, then you have two possibilities. 1) Plug in the power 2) Change the OS setting so that it will use full processing power. Also, the real threat here is, that your battery might break faster if you constantly running on full power without being connected to power